# How can I use Sum, Cast and Partition by functions together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

How can I use Sum, Cast and Partition by functions together?

I get error.

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '693.41' to data
>   type int."

I tried this

```
SUM(CAST([total price] AS INT)) OVER (PARTITION BY (ProjectType)) as TotalPriceV2
```

Full query is at the below.

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    [Project Manager], 
    Job#, 
    [Date], 
    [Job Type],
    first_value([Job Name]) OVER (PARTITION BY value_partition ORDER BY ID) CustomerGroup, Value_Partition 
    Customer,
    [Sales Rep1],
    DeliveryType,
    ProjectType,
    [Item Price],
    [Service Price],
    [Total Price],
    SUM(CAST([total price] AS INT)) OVER (PARTITION BY (ProjectType)) as TotalPriceV2
FROM (
    SELECT 
    ID,
    [Project Manager], Job#, [Date], [Job Type], [Job Name],Customer,[Sales Rep1],DeliveryType,ProjectType,[Item Price],[Service Price],[Total Price],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [JOB NAME] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS Value_Partition   
    FROM Testing2
    WHERE 
    [Date] IS NOT NULL AND 
    ([Date]  NOT LIKE '0' OR JOB# NOT LIKE '0' OR [JOB TYPE] NOT LIKE '0')
    AND [Project Manager] NOT LIKE 'ITEM / SERVICE'
) AS X
```

Comment: Why is `total price` a _character_ type?  Instead of `DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC`?  Also, why are you casting to `INT`, which would remove the decimal points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, identify the rows that have problems.  You are converting to an `int`, so:

```
select price
from Testing2
where try_convert(int, price) is null and price is not null;
```

At least some of the values will have decimal points (as in your example).  To see if this is the only problem, I would suggest converting to a decimal next:

```
select price
from Testing2
where try_convert(decimal(20, 4), price) is null and price is not null;
```

If this returns nothing, you are set.  If not, you will need to figure out how to address these exceptions.

Then, I would phrase the calculation using *decimals* and not floats:

```
SUM(TRY_CAST([total price] AS DECIMAL(20, 4))) OVER (PARTITION BY (ProjectType)) as TotalPriceV2
```

Monetary amounts should generally be represented using fixed-point values rather than approximate floating point values.  The issue with floating point values is that information may be lost.  Consider this example with `real`s:

```
select cast(1000000 as real) + cast(0.01 as real),
       cast(1000000 as decimal(20, 4)) + cast(0.01 as decimal(20, 4))
```

Comment: @gordon_linoff, thank you this ('SUM(TRY_CAST([total price] AS DECIMAL(20, 4))) OVER (PARTITION BY (ProjectType)) as TotalPriceV2') worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you cast it in inner query with decimal(16,9) instead of int

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    [Project Manager], 
    Job#, 
    [Date], 
    [Job Type],
    first_value([Job Name]) OVER (PARTITION BY value_partition ORDER BY ID) CustomerGroup, Value_Partition 
    Customer,
    [Sales Rep1],
    DeliveryType,
    ProjectType,
    [Item Price],
    [Service Price],
    [Total Price],
    SUM([total price]) OVER (PARTITION BY (ProjectType)) as TotalPriceV2
FROM (
    SELECT 
    ID,
    [Project Manager], Job#, [Date], [Job Type], [Job Name],Customer,[Sales Rep1],DeliveryType,ProjectType,[Item Price],[Service Price],cast([Total Price] as decimal(16,9)) as [Total Price],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [JOB NAME] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS Value_Partition   
    FROM Testing2
    WHERE 
    [Date] IS NOT NULL AND 
    ([Date]  NOT LIKE '0' OR JOB# NOT LIKE '0' OR [JOB TYPE] NOT LIKE '0')
    AND [Project Manager] NOT LIKE 'ITEM / SERVICE'
) AS X
```

Comment: "casting inside" isn't the important change you made - it was changing the destination cast type to `DECIMAL`.  You could have left the cast in the outer query and it would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a combination of string and number as your column value and you want to sum up the number. For `SQL Server 2012+` you can use `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` to avoid any casting errors.

[**TRY_CAST (Transact-SQL)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

In your scenario, you are not using proper data type for casting, you have values like `693.41` which can't be casted to `INT`, instead you should use `DECIMAL` datatype.

One more suggestion, instead of using `NOT LIKE`, better use `<>` in SQL Server like following.

Change

```
 ([Date]  NOT LIKE '0' OR JOB# NOT LIKE '0' OR [JOB TYPE] NOT LIKE '0')
```

to

```
 ([Date] <> '0' OR JOB# <> '0' OR [JOB TYPE] <> '0')
```

Comment: `TRY_CAST` will silently swallow the error, which is the **wrong** thing to do.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, you are right, I will mention in the answer.

Comment: @PSK "TRY_CAST (Transact-SQL)" returns NULL values

Answer (score 0):

Integer will not have decimal values, and it will throw an error.

If I use this, similar to the example you have.

```
Declare @val nvarchar(10) = '10.24' 

select   cast (@val as int)
```

I get this following error.

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '10.24' to data type int.
```

Now to avoid this error, I can round the digit to 0 decimal places and convert as Int. Also, I would recommend to use Try_Cast to avoid any cases of actual nvarchar values(it would convert it to null) if you are using sql server 2012 or more.

```
 Declare @val nvarchar(10) = '10.24' 

select   Try_cast (round(@val,0) as int)   as valuen
```

Output, I think this will work in your sum function.

```
valuen
10
```

Comment: `ROUND` is auto-casting to some form of decimal, so you don't need to use `CAST/`TRY_CAST`.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thank You for the feedback, that makes sense !

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to firstly convert the nvarchar value to decimal and then to integer:

```
CAST(CAST([total price] AS FLOAT) AS INT)
```

However, in this way the decimal part is lost if it matters to you.

Comment: It would be nice if I am able to get decimal however this works fine. Thank you for your answer @rad